# PHP CURL Problems with login

Tags: php, curl

I have problem with logging using cURL. This is my code:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL|E_STRICT);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://mysite.net/post/login.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, dirname(__FILE__).'/test.cookie'); // replace this with /tmp or something like that
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);

$data = array(
    'accountName' => 'name',
    'accountPassword' => 'password'
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $output; 
?>
```

What's wrong with my code? I cant login. Sorry for my english.

There's FORM form mysite.net

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="post/login.php">
<input type="hidden" name="securitytoken" value="672385374d4ed88e5ac0d6aaf29ae5f25280ed549a01f1.65943444">
<fieldset>
<h2>Account Login</h2>
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="accountName">Account name</label>
<div class="controls">
<input type="text" class="input-large" id="accountName" name="accountName">
</div>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
<label class="control-label" for="accountPassword">Account password</label>
<div class="controls">
<input type="password" class="input-large" id="accountPassword" name="accountPassword">
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-actions">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>&nbsp;
<button type="reset" class="btn">Cancel</button>
</div>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

Any ideas? What did I do wrong? I tried changing the code, used example codes. Still nothing.

Comment: maybe `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data, '', '&'))` ?

Comment: @Twisted1919 cURL automatically converts an array into a proper query, you don't need to do that.

Comment: @Barmar - i know there are servers that will get the `$_POST['something']` as `$_POST['&amp;something']`, don't really know why, but that's why i suggested using `http_build_query`.

Comment: @Twisted1919 That makes sense, since the documentation says that passing an array causes it to use `multipart/form-data` format. Ampersands are part of `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format.

Comment: @Barmar - got it, thanks for making time to clear this one out :)

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues.

1. You need to supply `securitytoken` as well as `accountName` and `accountPassword`. To do that you need to grab the page, extract token and post it with credentials
2. What enctype is used for the form normally (by browser)? You can look that up via any browser traffic addon. If you provide `$data` as array, cURL will use `multipart/form-data`. If it is a string - content type will be `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`